# Square Forms Factorization for long long int not working

Tags: c++, prime-factoring

I am trying to solve a programming problem where I have to calculate the prime factorization of any integer up to 2^63-1 (a long long int in C++). I am using Shank's Square Forms Factorization (SQUFOF) to calculate de divisors, but the problem is in some cases SQUFOF fails to find any divisor. here is the implemented code in C++:

```
typedef unsigned long long int lli;

lli LLIMAX=9223372036854775807ULL;
lli mult[16]={1ULL,3ULL,5ULL,7ULL,11ULL,15ULL,21ULL,33ULL,35ULL,55ULL,77ULL,105ULL,165ULL,231ULL,385ULL,1155ULL};

lli SQUFOF( lli N ) {
    lli D, Po, P, Pprev, Q, Qprev, q, b, r, s;
    int L, B, i;
    if (isSquare(N)) {
        return (lli)round(sqrt((double)ni));
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 16 && N <= LLIMAX/mult[k]; k++) {
        D = mult[k]*N;
        Po = Pprev = P = (lli)floor(sqrt((double)D));
        Qprev = 1ULL;
        Q = D - Po*Po;
        if (Q==0LL) {return mult[k];}
        L = 2 * ((int)floor(sqrt(2.0*round(sqrt((double)N)))));
        B = 3 * L;
        for (i = 2 ; i < B ; i++) {
            b = (Po + P)/Q;
            P = b*Q - P;
            q = Q;
            Q = Qprev + b*(Pprev - P);
            if (!(i & 1) && isSquare(Q)) break;
            Qprev = q;
            Pprev = P;
        };
        if (i >= B) continue;
        r = (lli)round(sqrt((double)Q));
        b = (Po - P)/r;
        Pprev = P = b*r + P;
        Qprev = r;
        Q = (D - Pprev*Pprev)/Qprev;
        i = 0;
        do {
            b = (Po + P)/Q;
            Pprev = P;
            P = b*Q - P;
            q = Q;
            Q = Qprev + b*(Pprev - P);
            Qprev = q;
            i++;
        } while (P != Pprev);
        r = gcd(N, Qprev);
        if (r != 1ULL && r != N) return r;
    }
    return 0ULL;
}
```

I use the deterministic Miller-Rabin test to ensure N is not a prime number before calling the function. I would like to know if SQUFOF can successfully find non-trivial factors of any composite number up to 2^63-1, and in such case I would like to know what are the problems of my code too. Thanks.

EDIT: It is not neccesary for me to find any errors on my code, it would be enough if someone could provide a C++ implementation of SQUFOF confirmed to be able to successfully extract non-trivial factors for integers up to 2^63-1. Thanks again.

Comment: This sounds like more of a question for Code Review than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am sorry if that is the case.

Comment: If the problem is the code doesn't work right, this is the place to ask, but be very clear about *what* doesn't work right. If the code works, but you suspect it can work better, then ask at Code Review. Regardless I recommend giving your variables meaningful names. It generally makes for a better quality of answer if the reviewers don't have to decode the code.

Comment: Please give an example of a number N for which the algorithm succeeds, and another example of a number N for which the algorithm fails.

Comment: The problem is I do not know for which cases the algorithm does not work. As I said is a programming problem, I submitted the code to a online judge and it did not accept the code because of a runtime error which happens when the codes does not find a nontrivial factor and returns 0. However I know the code works for numbers like 1073741796516192523 (this number is the product of 1000000007 and 1073741789, two relatively close primes) and 2^63-1.

Comment: You need to find a failing example so you can track through the code and find the error. Take a prime like 1000000007, multiply it by successive primes starting from 1073741789, submit each of those semi-primes to the factoring program, and find one that fails. Then instrument the code, or run it under a debugger, and find out what is going wrong.

Comment: I found a number: 122630730868806119. Its factorization is 27883*4398046511093, but the algorithm returns 0.

Comment: I have managed to factor the number by taking multipliers not just from the list but from from any integer (1,2,3,4,...). However my code still was rejected.

Comment: My SQUFOF [implementation](https://programmingpraxis.com/2010/08/24/daniel-shanks-square-form-factorization-algorithm/) factored 122630730868806119. You can see it at [http://ideone.com/914RuH](http://ideone.com/914RuH), where about 28000 lines have been cut off. It's written in Scheme, not C++, but you can compare your intermediate values to mine and see where you are going wrong.